# Adobe Air Settings absent in Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: air, adobe, settings, dreamweaver

For the love of me I don't know why I can't get my Dreamweaver CS6 copy to pick up the Adobe Air Settings option in the Site menu of the application.

[image: Adobe Air Settings missing in the options]

Below is what it looks like when opened

[image: Air settings when opened]

I basically am running a Windows 8.1 system and I have followed all the instructions to get the Adobe Air Extension for Dreamweaver installed

[image]

I have restarted Dreamweaver CS6 so many times as instructed by the installation process but still do not have the options needed for Air Development in Dreamweaver CS6 available and its driving me nuts. There is simply no issue documenting this anywhere else online as I have literally spent my whole day searching so it almost feels like I am all alone.

Any help with this will very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am also looking for same solution i have installed AIR extension for dreamweaver but the option in Site > Air Application Settings is disabled and don't know how to enable it.

Comment: Niranjan: yeah, it's not available for this particular version of Dreamweaver. I had to install an older version for it to work, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got that option enabled in dreamweaver cs6 but for that you need to create new site put in your html and swf files in that site then select site you created then option in Site > Air Application Settings is available for use.